# Lettuce Profiles

Tags: cucumber, bdd, lettuce

[Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) lets you define [profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml) in a cucumber.yml file - which are essentially command line arguments that can be reused. Does anyone know if it's possible to accomplish the same with [lettuce](http://lettuce.it/)? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lettuce doesn't support profiles. There was an issue open about supporting arbitrary command line parameters but it was closed and apparently will not be implemented. Here's a link to the discusson (there's a workaround discussed there as well) [Lettuce command line params](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/issues/68)

Comment: Yup.. I actually saw [that](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/lettuce/issues/68) but forgot to post an answer! I ended up using both sys.argv and the environment. Thanks!

Comment: There's actually another BDD tool for python called bahave [(behave_on_github)](https://github.com/behave/behave) and it already supports command line arguments (in the master branch). The next release available on pip will have it (should be published in February)